# Images and Video not loading on Github Pages

Tags: image, github-pages

I'm working on a website with Github pages. My code has been reviewed and it said to be correct, but my images and video do not display when I look at the site on my browser. I've read a bunch of similar questions on this site, but the answer was always that the file path was case sensitive. My case is the same, it still doesn't work.

I've tried to use the "raw" url from github. Tried with a ./ and just a / no luck. My email is verified.

Any other suggestions? Thanks!!

https://jeanninejacobs.github.io/excursion/

Answer (score 0):

The top level of your site is at `https://jeanninejacobs.github.io/excursion/`.

That means that an image located at `resources/images/camp.jpg` has a full path of `https://jeanninejacobs.github.io/excursion/resources/images/camp.jpg`.

However, you're using `/resources/images/camp.jpg` which is relative to the top of the domain, in other words relative to `https://jeanninejacobs.github.io`. That means `/resources/images/camp.jpg` references `https://jeanninejacobs.github.io/resources/images/camp.jpg`, which is wrong because it's missing the `excursion` subdirectory.

The easiest way to fix your problem is to just use `/excursion/resources/images/camp.jpg` instead of `/resources/images/camp.jpg`.

Or you could use a custom domain and get rid of the `excursion` subdirectory.

There are fancier options if you need something more specific, but hopefully this gets you going in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

I have also found that the file extension names are case sensitive. For Example, if the files are named *.JPG, the file path must also be in all caps.